# Angular : How to use JWT Authentication with an API call

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, angular6, jwt

I am following [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) article. The author is using `fake-backend.ts` to intercept an api call whose url ends with `/api/authenticate` and check users based on their username and password from a static array.

When the user submit form with username and password then it calls `authentication.service.ts` login function which post call on path `/api/authenticate` and as the call has an url ending with `/api/authenticate` so now here `fake-backend.ts` comes into play which is validating user from static array. After successful authentication it generates a token and control goes back to `authentication.service.ts` to map response object

I bit change this `fake-backend.ts` with calling an api to validate users from db. But I am getting below error.

> Http failure response for https://localhost:44348/api/authenticate:
>   404 OK

Also call not going back to `authentication.service.ts` to map response object.

```
if (request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && request.method === 'POST') {
const UserName = request.body.username;
const Password = request.body.password;
var credentials = { UserName, Password };
//return this.employeeService.autheticateEmployeeByCredentials(credentials);
this.employeeService.autheticateEmployeeByCredentials(credentials).subscribe((res) => {
if (res == 1) 
    return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: { token: 'fake-jwt-token' } }));    
else 
      return throwError({ error: { message: 'Username or password is incorrect' } });   
  });
}
```

**Edit :**
I am using an api controller and validating from that returning 1 if its there in db else 0. Also getting response from api but control does not do back to authentication.service.ts but goes to `login.component.ts` subscribe and throws this error.

Comment: Have you check these blog?
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Another great resource to know regarding JSON Web Tokens:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt/

Comment: What and where is your backend?

Comment: I have updated question pls check edit part..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the 404 in your response is a **NotFound** response - meaning, your service cannot see that url. 
By default, all non-success responsed from the server (responses with status code outside the range 200-299) are treated as error responses, which means they trigger an error. From the looks of it, fake-backend does not have a try-catch mechanism, hence the 404 will not hit any subscriptions down the promise chain.

So to solve your problem, I suggest you use an application like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)
 to verify that your https://localhost:44348/api is indeed working.

Then where it says `return next.handle(request);`, use catchError to handle non-success responses from your api, like in the example below. Then in your authentication.service.ts you can do something like `authenticateUser(/*parameters*/).subscribe(response => if(response.body.error) {/*handle error */} else {/*do your normal stuff */});`

```js
 return next.handle(request).pipe(
              catchError(error => {
                return of(
                  new HttpResponse({
                    status: 200,
                    body: {
                      error: {
                        responseMessage: 'Some Error Accessing API'
                      }
                      /**some response body you can surely handle in authentication.service.ts */
                    }
                  })
                );
              })
            );
```

To fully address your specific issue, would you mind posting your full FakeBackendInterceptor class.

Comment: its same as in article @gerryc.inc, I have pasted which I have changed. And the problem is that its not waiting for the response from the service which is validating user from backend "autheticateEmployeeByCredentials"..

Comment: Lets see the autheticateEmployeeByCredentials method. I'm interested in seeing how it is handling the result from the HttpClient call (I assume you are using HttpClient service to do the actual call to the backend).

Comment: sry for replying late bcz of weekends, yea its a simple httpclient service calling backing nothing special in it..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two problems(or more perhaps) but let's fix the first one...

You need to return the call to employeservice in order to not break the promise chain.

Also, can you validate that your backend is listening at https://localhost:44348/api and not your frontend?

Comment: that is the issue i don't know how to return service call without breaking the promise chain..

Comment: Oops, sorry for multiple answer... I'm on my phone and didn't realise I was reposting and answer...

Answer (score 0):

Humm, it seems like your going against the grain here...

In his example he faked his backend with that interceptor.

```
if (request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && request.method === 'POST') { const UserName = request.body.username; const Password = request.body.password; var credentials = { UserName, Password }; //return this.employeeService.autheticateEmployeeByCredentials(credentials); this.employeeService.autheticateEmployeeByCredentials(credentials).subscribe((res) => { if (res == 1) return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: { token: 'fake-jwt-token' } })); else return throwError({ error: { message: 'Username or password is incorrect' } }); });
```

So if you would use your backend for authentication for instance, you should remove this.

After that, in the authentication service you should  call to the url your backend is listening on.

Comment: I have tried this also but how generate token then  "return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: { token: 'fake-jwt-token' } }));", also i need to get to know what was the response from api 0 or 1..

Comment: The status code and the header should be set by your backend, not your frontend.

I suggest you that if your api would return 1 it should return the response status 200 with token header instead.

When it would return 0 then you should return a response with a status code 401.